# EXCEL 2007 Macro insert x value of rows

Tags: loops, excel, variables, vba

Hi i have tried to make a Macro that could insert x number of rows but it won't work.
I would be very grateful for any help! :)

```
Sub Makro4()
'
' Makro4 Makro
'
' Kortkommando: Ctrl+j
'
    Dim Rng
    Dim k
    Rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
    For Rng = k To Rng
    k = k + 1
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Makro4()
    Dim Rng As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim rRange As Range

    Set rRange = Selection

    Rng = InputBox("Enter number:.")
    For k = 1 To Rng
        Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
              CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next
End Sub
```

Your for loop did not make sense and you exited inside it so it would have inserted always just one row. I fixed it and show how to insert rows.